Capturing complete previous URL in Javascript
I have a website and people are coming from different platforms like facebook and instagram by clicking on a link. so I am capturing the previous URL (URL Referrer ) using " var referrerURL1 = document.referrer; "
but, for example if this is the complete previous URL a person came from ( Redirected URL from the facebook ) -
https://l.facebook.com/l.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fkalamandir.com%2Fgreen-kanchipuram-sku-200189&h=AT0tQMzyrc0xadEE9xtnnz7ajPo5ZNjj7fX3OXXSjB-4CVBKR3pFTNdwqFWTOUSH6LlxjGomkY2aDJQtH3rO80rKhn5XI0RlvgnONM3-EWUDn5rSOZNYAaE0S0OplhQ9k5NXVXJyc86ye8IgA75e&__tn__=-UK-R&c[0]=AT1V66bvAmheMuQADRZ1rshXtrT-6TjOjaeue6F1PIFPao40uikG4WzamKssvczyicEWYIKM3_JzwH9LkiJBoJhZhJRdYbPGODgQuSgzxYzVXVs--GwAtwnjlhw5tXznLE4RVhX-ki92yk0NVd55o-qxoi6r2mCXPx_rDxf7eCqauRQzeAf9zfjZVBaKraqtmGqtQ2Ve8O_lmcMZldlg80DYAtTPD5YHRmyOppyqCJZbHw
I am able to capture - https://l.facebook.com/ this much only using document.referrer
how do i capture the complete URL.
I tried using this function (var referrerURL1 = document.referrer) and printed it on console got only (https://l.facebook.com/) this part

You can't reliably get the document.referrer since it depends on the sites Referrer-Policy

Perhaps facebook has some paid service where you can see the outgoing link when it is your server?
